Inconsistency in logged fingerprint (abuse/fraud combat) on Wordpress
I'm working on a WordPress site with BuddyPress, the BuddyX Pro theme, and the Wise Chat Pro plugin. Recently, I’ve been tackling abuse on the group chat page, where users often bypass IP-based bans using TOR or VPNs. To improve security, I wrote a custom plugin that does the following:
Plugin functionality:

IP lookup: The plugin uses MaxMind to check the user's IP location and identify if it's a known proxy or VPN. Optionally, it can also query the ProxyCheck.io API (currently disabled).
Device fingerprinting: For each unique device, a set of fingerprints is generated (both advanced—based on server-side and client-side data—and fallback, using only server-side data). Note: I am aware this is not 100% fool-proof, but in my use-case I would like to have it as an extra resource.
Bot whitelisting: Known bots (e.g., Google, Microsoft) are whitelisted and always allowed to enter.
Conditional rules: IPs from certain countries (e.g., China, Russia) are blocked and users are redirected to another page.

How it works:

IP blocks: IPs that don’t meet the conditions (e.g., geographic location, VPN status) are correctly redirected.
Fingerprint generation: Two sets of fingerprints (advanced and fallback) are generated, hashed, and saved in a protected JSON file for 5 days before being purged.
Blocking fingerprints: I added a feature to manually block specific fingerprints as a last resort. This works as intended, but I’ve run into an issue where the fingerprint generated and checked against the blocklist does not match the one written to the JSON file.

The issue:
I generate a set of 2 fingerprints (advanced and fallback):
function generate_fingerprint() {
    $fallback = generate_fallback_fingerprint();
    $advanced = generate_advanced_fingerprint();
    $combined = md5($fallback . $advanced);
    $reliability = calculate_reliability_score();
    
    return [
        'fallback_fingerprint' => $fallback,
        'advanced_fingerprint' => $combined,
        'reliability_score' => $reliability
    ];
}

This set of fingerprings is than saved to a fingerprints.json logfile:
function save_fingerprint($ip, $fingerprint_data) {
    $data = [];
    if (file_exists(FINGERPRINT_FILE)) {
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents(FINGERPRINT_FILE), true) ?? [];
    }
    $timestamp = time();
    $key = $ip . '_' . $timestamp;
    $data[$key] = [
        'ip' => $ip,
        'fallback_fingerprint' => $fingerprint_data['fallback_fingerprint'],
        'advanced_fingerprint' => $fingerprint_data['advanced_fingerprint'],
        'reliability_score' => $fingerprint_data['reliability_score'],
        'timestamp' => $timestamp,
        // 'client_data' => $_POST  // Only enabled when needed for debugging
    ];
    file_put_contents(FINGERPRINT_FILE, json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}

When the user returns, I would expect that the same fingerprint (advanced or fallback) that is generated and logged to the fingerprints.json would be recognized and if held against the blocklist (blocked_fingerprints.json), would result in the user being redirected as expected (in case of a blocked fingerprint).
   $blocked_fingerprints = get_blocked_fingerprints();
    if (in_array($fingerprint_data['fallback_fingerprint'], $blocked_fingerprints)) {
        wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url);
        exit;
    }
    if (in_array($fingerprint_data['advanced_fingerprint'], $blocked_fingerprints)) {
        wp_safe_redirect($redirect_url);
        exit;
    }

However, this does not happen.
The fingerprints generated and checked against the blocklist do not match the one written to the JSON file.
I have tried to see what fingerprints are checked against the blocklist, by adding them to my errorlog:
$fingerprint_data = generate_fingerprint();
save_fingerprint($fingerprint_data);
error_log("Fingerprint saved for IP: $ip");
The error log than shows a different set of fingerprints than the one written to the fingerprints.json file. This suggests there's some kind of mismatch in how the fingerprint is generated upon checking the blocklist. Even for the serverside (fallback) fingerprint, which should always be identical. So there seems to be a different way the fingerprints get calculated and/or hashed and I can not figure out how or why. I have no idea what the difference is between both situations.
My full code files (for review) are located here:
https://pastebin.com/u/flower88/1/JUEMKr6z
The password to the files is: G3F80fhczm
My setup:

/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/block-anonymous.php
/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/fingerprint.js (loaded in the page header)
The snippet is executed via the WPCode plugin in the header of the specific page.

What works:

IPs that don’t meet the criteria are correctly redirected.
Whitelisted bots are allowed as expected.
The two sets of fingerprints (advanced and fallback) are generated and stored in the JSON file correctly. Note: These fingerprints remain identical, stable and consistent over multiple sessions and days and are unique to each device.
Old fingerprints are purged after 5 days.
Blocking specific fingerprints works, but the fingerprint comparison is inconsistent.

What i’ve tried:

Logging shows me that the generated fingerprints that are being checked against the blocked fingerprints do not match, for both advanced and fallback fingerprint alike
Pause the PHP file with sleep() before adding block, to give the site enough time to generate the correct fingerprint (did not work)
I’ve spent 4 days troubleshooting this issue and even consulted ChatGPT for help, but I haven’t found a solution yet. At this point I am even doubting if I understand the issue correctly. ChatGPT hasn't been helpful as I have been going into circles over and over.
I am out of ideas and would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to resolve the fingerprint mismatch with a clean, fresh, human look at it.

Thank you very much in advance!

I haven't looked through everything, but at first glance, I wonder if your call to file_put_contents is inadvertently overwriting the file with a single JSON entry instead of appending. You may want to check that and ensure the FILE_APPEND flag is set. file_put_contents

Looking through your code, I would start by debugging the fingerprint generation functions. There might be a piece of data that's being set differently on each request and affecting one of the generated hashes. If you have breakpoint debugging and XDebug, that would be ideal. Otherwise, you can use a simple dump-and-die approach to determine if you're getting different hash calculations from multiple requests. Check the results of both generate_fallback_fingerprint as well as generate_advanced_fingerprint separately to see if that's the case

If either of those functions are returning a different hash calculation on multiple requests from the same user (ie: you) then that's going to affect the combined hash. Once that's been determined, you'll want to debug each piece of data you're looking at to see which one is different from request to request.

@maiorano84 thank you for your swift response. I have indeed tried to debug this logging it in both console and php error log. I get inconsistent and different results for hashes, only confusing the hell out of me :) The point is, even with raw clientdata logged, I have no idea how the hash is calculated into JSON and than into MD5. Even with the same dataset, a different hash is generated in some cases. The confusing part is you would expect variations in the fingerprints.json file as well. But those are stable over multiple days and sessions en unique to each visitor.

It's hard to say without knowing what the raw data is. Start with the generate_advanced_fingerprint hash, and make several requests with the same data and check the contents of json_encode($components) as well as the computed hash. You should be able to at least eyeball whether each request payload is the same or not, and whether or not the MD5 hash is generating a different computation each time on the same payload (it shouldn't, but we should rule it out first).

As an overall suggestion, I don't generally recommend a fingerprinting approach to prevent abuse. These can be brittle can pretty easily be forged, which can result in a fair bit of wasted effort. Instead, I think using something like a reCaptcha v3 as a means to protect your endpoint should provide a more stable check using Google's own services.

@maiorano84, sorry for being unclear. I can confirm it is stable. And I know it is not 100% foolproof.

Cool. If generate_advanced_fingerprint is stable, then generate_fallback_fingerprint is likely your culprit. In the same way you did before, check the result of both your raw string data, as well as the computed hash across multiple requests, and see if any of the server data changes from request to request.

Let's move this discussion to chat

No it does not. I have tested this extensively to make sure that did not happen. At least not the fingerprints written to my JSON file. I get a totally different hash when logging it to the error log. for both advanced and fallback alike.

Click the chat link above. I have some time to work with you in real-time so we don't blow up the comments section.

@maiorano84 I would love to, but it tells me i do not have enough "reputation" (need 20, I seem to have 11) to be able to use the chat.... Let me look into this real quick. Give me a bit.

Ugh, that's annoying. I checked room permissions, and it seems I can't add you explicitly either. I'll leave the room for now. In the meantime, just to clarify from the last message: If I understand correctly, we're getting stable computed hashes both from generate_advanced_fingerprint as well as generate_fallback_fingerprint, however the $combined result is not returning a stable result on each request?

@maiorano84 happy to clarify, added more context here: https://pastebin.com/F8CVuAxd Both fallback_fingerprint and advanced_fingerprint (which is combined) are stable and consistent. Hope this helps.

Nothing in particular is jumping out at me. You're right that this is a tricky one to track down. I'd have to sandbox this code and test with some static values and test data to fully track down what might be happening here. I'll let someone else chime in here in case they see anything, but overall I think you've asked a really good question here and you've put together a lot of information for us to work with. That's a welcome rarity here, so thank you for that. I'll keep an eye on this and follow up later as time allows.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I managed to figure this one out by myself eventually.
For reference, this is what I did:

Clearly clarified fingerprint components (serverside, clientside, combined) for both generating and saving the fingerprint

    function generate_fingerprint() {
        static $cached_fingerprint = null;
        
        if ($cached_fingerprint !== null) {
            return $cached_fingerprint;
        }
        
        $fallback = generate_fallback_fingerprint();
        $advanced_client = generate_advanced_fingerprint();
        $combined = md5($fallback . $advanced_client);
        $reliability = calculate_reliability_score();
        
        $fingerprint = [
            'fallback_fingerprint' => $fallback,
            'advanced_fingerprint' => $combined,
            'advanced_client_only' => $advanced_client,
            'reliability_score' => $reliability
        ];
        $cached_fingerprint = $fingerprint;
        return $fingerprint;
    }

    function save_fingerprint($ip, $fingerprint_data) {
        $data = [];
        if (file_exists(FINGERPRINT_FILE)) {
            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents(FINGERPRINT_FILE), true) ?? [];
        }
        $timestamp = time();
        $key = $ip . '_' . $timestamp;
        $data[$key] = [
            'ip' => $ip,
            'fallback_fingerprint' => $fingerprint_data['fallback_fingerprint'],
            'advanced_fingerprint' => $fingerprint_data['advanced_fingerprint'],
            'advanced_client_only' => $fingerprint_data['advanced_client_only'],
            'reliability_score' => $fingerprint_data['reliability_score'],
            'timestamp' => $timestamp,
        ];
    
        // Voeg client_data toe als de constante is gedefinieerd en true is
        if (defined('SAVE_CLIENT_DATA') && SAVE_CLIENT_DATA) {
            $data[$key]['client_data'] = $_POST;
        }
    
        file_put_contents(FINGERPRINT_FILE, json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }


Added the same logic to the blocking

    function is_fingerprint_blocked($fingerprint) {
        $blocked_fingerprints = get_blocked_fingerprints();
        $is_post_request = ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FINGERPRINT_REQUEST']));
        $redirect_type = $is_post_request ? "JavaScript redirect" : "wp_safe_redirect";
        $ip = get_visitor_ip();
    
        $fingerprint_types = [
            'fallback_fingerprint' => 'fallback',
            'advanced_fingerprint' => 'gecombineerde advanced',
            'advanced_client_only' => 'clientside-only advanced'
        ];
    
        foreach ($fingerprint_types as $key => $type) {
            if (isset($fingerprint[$key]) && in_array($fingerprint[$key], $blocked_fingerprints)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    
        return false;
    }

I no longer need help, so resolving my own request.
